# XMLHTTPRequest vulnerabilities when doing cross origin requests from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

You can do cross origin requests with Chrome extensions. I created a test Chrome extension to fiddle with this. It gets all the code in a specific page from a site at the click of a button.

All I want from the page is data (just some text and numbers) to then display it in the options page of the extension.

The way I'm extracting this data is by traversing the document in the response (the `response` or `responseXML` property of the request). For example, I use `querySelectorAll` to get a bunch of elements, then I put all of their `textContent` properties in an array, then I put each element on the array in a `<ul>` in the DOM of the extension page.

Lastly, after I request a particular page from the site, I store the response document in my `localStorage` (only the last page requested will be stored, overwriting the previous page stored). I'm doing this by storing the `outerHTML` of the response element (through `document.documentElement.outerHTML`). Then when I refresh the extension page, I use `DOMParser` and `parseFromString` to convert it back to a document. After it's been converted back to a document, the stuff in the previous paragraph happens again (the DOM traversing and extraction of data).

Any potential security issues?

MDN says this:

> "Processing a responseText property containing an HTML document If you
>   use XMLHttpRequest to get the content of a remote HTML webpage, the
>   responseText property is a string containing the raw HTML. This could
>   prove difficult to manipulate and analyze. There are three primary
>   ways to analyze and parse this raw HTML string:
>
> 1. Use the XMLHttpRequest.responseXML property as covered in the article 
>      https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest
> 2. HTML in XMLHttpRequest. Inject the content into the body of a document
>      fragment via fragment.body.innerHTML and traverse the DOM of the
>      fragment.
> 3. RegExp can be used if you always know the content of the
>      HTML responseText beforehand. You might want to remove line breaks, if
>      you use RegExp to scan with regard to linebreaks. However, this method
>      is a "last resort" since if the HTML code changes slightly, the method
>      will likely fail."

I am using the first method.

This page talks about dangerous and safe methods of handling the response (although here it's talking about responseText, not an html document gotten from response or responseXML):
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr

Summary:

```
    // 1. WARNING! Might be evaluating an evil script!
    var resp = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");

    // 2. WARNING! Might be injecting a malicious script!
    document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

    // 3. JSON.parse does not evaluate the attacker's scripts.
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    // 4. innerText does not let the attacker inject HTML elements.
    document.getElementById("resp").innerText = xhr.responseText;
```

The only issue here is number 2. I have used innerHTML to create a `<li>`'s in a `<ul>` with data from the response doc. Now, I know this site, but I guess I could change this to not use innerHTML.

Comment: Style or script elements? Btw, I see that Firefox won't even allow extensions with innerHTML. Don't know about Chrome.

I tested adding ```<img src="x" onerror="alert(1)">``` to a document in an iframe and it actually runs the alert too. That's scary. 

I guess if I take a string from the response doc and add it to the textContent property of an element in my main doc I should be fine in all cases right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe API/properties:

- `textContent` or `innerText` are absolutely secure
- `responseXML` is secure, see [step 5 in XHR specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#document-response):

  > scripting support disabled on received bytes
- `DOMParser` API is secure just the same.

Potentially unsafe:

- `innerHTML` won't run `<script>` elements, see ([HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element)):

  > When inserted using the innerHTML and outerHTML attributes, they do not execute at all.

  but it'll run inline code in event handler attributes like `<img src="x" onerror="alert(1)">` and although normally this won't run in an extension page due to the default CSP [forbidding inline code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) in extension pages, but many authors need to relax the CSP.

  Even if you didn't relax the default CSP and want to use the raw foreign html in the main document, you need to strip `<style>` and `<link>` elements as those can alter the main page appearance, remove the `on` attributes, `<script>` elements as well (just for consistency). Or put that HTML inside an [iframe with `sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) attribute instead.

  There's also Mozilla's policy to consider:

  > If your project is one that will undergo any form of security review, using innerHTML most likely will result in your code being rejected. For example, if you use innerHTML in a browser extension and submit the extension to addons.mozilla.org, it will not pass the automated review process.

Comment: Your recommendation about stripping elements applies only if I'm planning to insert elements in the response doc into my main doc correct? If I'm just accessing specific properties of elements in the response doc, that doesn't apply?

Comment: Yes. If you use a sandboxed iframe it blocks scripts by default.

Comment: For picking elements, also yes, provided you don't overlook a child element or a `on` event attribute.